# Google Drive API files by created Date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

My goal is to delete files from a specific folder older than 60 days.

I have a script as follows (based on code from another post I can't find anymore):

```js
function getOldFileIDs() {
  var fileIDs = [];
  // Old date is 60 days
  var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1000*24*60;
  var cutOffDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(oldDate), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  // Get folderID using the URL on google drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXX'); 
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileIDs.push(file.getId());
    Logger.log('ID: ' + file.getId() + ', Name: ' + file.getName());
  }
  return fileIDs;
};

function deleteFiles() {
  var fileIDs = getOldFileIDs();
  fileIDs.forEach(function(fileID) {
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).setTrashed(true);
  });
};
```

This code works but it uses "modifiedDate"  When I look in the folder, I see there are many very old files with a "modified" date of today for some reason, but the "Created" date seems correct.

Therefore, I tried changing the code to "createdDate" but that doesn't work.

I decided to actually look at the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms

It seems like "modifiedDate" isn't even listed yet it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete old files:

```
function delOldFiles() {
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate() - 60).valueOf();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXX'); 
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if(new Date(file.getDateCreated()).valueOf() < dtv) {
      Drive.Files.remove(file.getId());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked after I changed to getDateCreated()

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure which one you wanted

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue and workaround:

- The parameter of "searchFiles" method uses the search query for Drive API v2. When I tested `createdDate > '####-##-##'` for "searchFiles" and "Files: list" of Drive API v2, I confirmed errors like `Invalid argument: q` and `Invalid query` occurred, respectively. This has already been mentioned in [Lorena Gomez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74117194)
- Fortunately, when Drive API v3 is used, `createdTime` can be used. `createdTime` of Drive API v3 is the same with `createdDate` of Drive API v2. In this answer, as a workaround, I would like to propose using Drive API v3 instead of Drive API v2 ("searchFiles" of DriveApp). I have already posted this workaround at [this post](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/wujyXLzl6wY). But, this has not been posted in Stackoverflow. When this is posted here, I thought that it might be useful for other users.

When Drive API v3 is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

This script uses Drive API. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function getOldFileIDs() {
  var folderId = "###"; // Please set your folder ID.
  var fileIDs = [];

  // Old date is 60 days
  var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 60;
  var cutOffDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(oldDate), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  var query = `'${folderId}' in parents and createdTime < '${cutOffDate}' and trashed=false`;
  var pageToken = "";
  do {
    var url = encodeURI(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=${query}&pageSize=1000&pageToken=${pageToken}&fields=files(id,name,createdTime),nextPageToken&orderBy=createdTime`);
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
    var obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
    if (obj.files.length > 0) {
      fileIDs = [...fileIDs, ...obj.files.map(({ id }) => id)];
      obj.files.forEach(({ id, name, createdTime }) => Logger.log(JSON.stringify({ id, name, createdTime })));
    }
    pageToken = obj.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  return fileIDs;
}
```

- When this script is run, the file list including file IDs is retrieved with the search query of `'${folderId}' in parents and createdTime < '${cutOffDate}' and trashed=false`.
- When you are not required to check the process, please remove `obj.files.forEach(({ id, name, createdTime }) => Logger.log(JSON.stringify({ id, name, createdTime })));`.

#### Note:

As additional information, in order to remove the files, when the number of files is large when `setTrashed` is run in a loop, the process cost becomes high. In this case, how about using batch requests? When batch requests are used, the process cost can be reduced. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/efficient-file-management-using-batch-requests-google-apps-script)

When batch requests are used with Google Apps Script, a script is a bit complicated. So, I created a Google Apps Script library. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest) When your script of `deleteFiles()` is modified for removing the files with the batch requests, how about the following modification?

##### 1. Install Google Apps Script library.

Please install the Google Apps Script library. You can see how to install it [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest#how-to-install).

##### 2. Sample script.

In this sample, the result is the same with `setTrashed`. The files of `fileIDs` are moved to the trash box.

```js
function deleteFiles() {
  var fileIDs = getOldFileIDs();
  var requests = fileIDs.map(id => ({
    method: "PATCH",
    endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${id}`,
    requestBody: { trashed: true },
  }));
  var result = BatchRequest.EDo({ batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests });
  console.log(result);
}
```

If you want to completely delete the files of `fileIDs`, please use the following script. **But, this script completely deletes the files. So, please be careful about this. So, I would like to recommend using the above script.** After you check the files in the trash box, you can empty the trash box.

```js
function deleteFiles() {
  var fileIDs = getOldFileIDs();
  var requests = fileIDs.map(id => ({
    method: "DELETE",
    endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${id}`,
  }));
  var result = BatchRequest.EDo({ batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests });
  console.log(result);
}
```

#### References:

- [Files: list of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [BatchRequest of Google Apps Script library](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question:

> Therefore, I tried changing the code to "createdDate" but that doesn't work.

This seems to be an issue which has already been reported in this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79355545), you can keep track of this to see any updates in the future, [this](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/wujyXLzl6wY) is another thread related to the issue. @Cooper's answer is a good workaround to achieve what you're looking for.