DriveApp.searchFiles("createdDate = '2024-07-23'") - invalid argument?
Trying to search for files that were created on a given date using the following:
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("createdDate = '2024-07-23'");

when then doing files.next(), I'm getting this:
Exception: Invalid argument: q

I have reviewed the Drive v2 API and the query is correct, so why am I get this response? Using modifiedDate works, but not createdDate (or v3's createdTime).
I expected to get the FileIterator, instead got Exception: Invalid argument: q

There is indeed a createDate in v2 of the Drive API, which is what Google Apps Script uses. It was changed to createdTime in v3.

Okay thanks I didn't know that.

But it still looks like it's a Date Object and not a string so how do you expect to compare a Date Object to a string.  Maybe try valueOf()?

In your situation, this answer might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74118817

It was changed to createdTime in v3. Correct, but does it not refer to searching for shared drives not files. I wonder whether modifiedTime is the correct parameter - which requires date and time.

How about... var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('modifiedDate = "2024-07-23"')
